# ¿Como pasar datos de un JTable a un JDialog?

Tags: java, mvc, jtable, jtextfield

Buenas, estoy intentando pasar datos de un **JTable** a un **JDialog** (adjunto código).

También he probado este código con un **JFrame** y todos los datos pasaron a este último(ya puse public y static a ambos **JTextField**), entonces ¿hay algo malo en el código que hice o es que al usar un **JDialog** se necesita agregar más cosas?.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

[image: DatosProductos]

[image: Listar]

```
private void editar() {

    ProductoEditar2 edita = new ProductoEditar2(this,true);

    edita.setVisible(true);
    int seleccionar = tblProductos.getSelectedRow();
    if (seleccionar >= 0) {
        Object[] filaselect = {
            tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 0),
            tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 1),
            tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 2)};
        ProductoEditar2.tnombre.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[0]));
        ProductoEditar2.tcantidad.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[1]));
        ProductoEditar2.tprecio.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[2]));
    }
```

Comment: Edita es tu JDialog? Podrías poner el código de tu clase producto editar?

Comment: No amigo, edita es el método que debería pasar los datos de ese JFrame al JDialog, y con respecto a la clase ProductoEditar lo hice por JFrameForm(Jalar opciones y pegar)                                              
  `private javax.swing.JButton btnCerrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField tcantidad;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField tnombre;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField tprecio;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esto en tu clase editar2.

```
public javax.swing.JTextField tcantidad; 
public javax.swing.JTextField tnombre; 
public javax.swing.JTextField tprecio;
```

Y pon tu método editar así:

```
private void editar() {

    ProductoEditar2 edita = new ProductoEditar2(this,true);

    int seleccionar = tblProductos.getSelectedRow();
    if (seleccionar >= 0) {
        Object[] filaselect = {
            tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 0),
            tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 1),
            tblProductos.getValueAt(seleccionar, 2)};
        edita.tnombre.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[0]));
        edita.tcantidad.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[1]));
        edita.tprecio.setText(String.valueOf(filaselect[2]));
    }


    edita.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Funcionoooo, muchas gracias :D!!!

Comment: De nada, estamos para ayudar ;)